# herokuへpushできません。Failed to install gems via Bundler.Push rejected, failed to compile Multipack app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

現在、理由は不明なのですが、
突然herokuへpushしようとするとエラーが出るようになってしまいました。

```
% git push heroku master --force
Fetching repository, done.
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> Multipack app detected
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/markaschneider/heroku-buildpack-ruby-ffmpeg-sox.git
=====> Detected Framework: Ruby
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.7.12
   Ruby version change detected. Clearing bundler cache.
   Old: ruby 2.0.0p598 (2014-11-13 revision 48408) [x86_64-linux]
   New: ruby 2.0.0p643 (2015-02-25 revision 49749) [x86_64-linux]
   Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
   Fetching source index from http://rubygems.org/
   Net::HTTPNotFound: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not
   exist.</Message><Key>quick/Marshal.4.8/0.1.0.gemspec.rz</Key><RequestId></RequestId><HostId></HostId></Error>
   Bundler Output: Fetching source index from http://rubygems.org/
   Net::HTTPNotFound: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not
   exist.</Message><Key>quick/Marshal.4.8/0.1.0.gemspec.rz</Key><RequestId></RequestId><HostId></HostId></Error>
!
!     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
!

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Multipack app

To git@heroku.com:app.git
! [remote rejected] master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:app.git'
```

gitでいくら遡っても、以前pushできていた物まで同じエラーが出てしまうのですが、どこを直せば良いのでしょうか？何時間考えても分かりません。

[Heroku push rejected, Ruby Version Changed Detected, Could not find net-scp-1.0.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033607/heroku-push-rejected-ruby-version-changed-detected-could-not-find-net-scp-1-0)
を参考に
    gem cleanup  
    bundle update 
してみたり、
package.json
をルートに加えてみたりしましたが、何も変わりません。

ヒントだけでも教えていただければ、幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

もう既に解決されているかもしれませんが、試しに同じbuildpackでRails4.2をインストールしてみたところうまく同様のエラーは発生しませんでしたので、気になる点だけお伝えしておきます。

- 現在はGemfileのsourceは `http` ではなく `https` が標準になっているので変更してみてはどうでしょう。
- Gemfileの中にyankされた(リリースが取りけされた)バージョンのgemがない確認してみてください。この場合、ローカルには既にインストールできているので動作に問題がありませんが、新たにインストールしようとすると失敗することになります。

完全な回答になっておらず申し訳ありませんが、ヒントになれば幸いです。

Comment: この問題は、未だ問題自体は解決しなかったが、何とかした記憶があります(別のbuildpackを使用？)。

http、httpsにつきましては当時も指摘を受け、双方試し解決しませんでした。
後者につきましては、考えたこともありませんでした。又一つ勉強になりました。
大変助かります、ありがとうございます。